# Referencing column in Snowflake JS UDF

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a JS UDF in Snowflake that has two inputs: a string from a column, and then another string that I use to create a mapping object.

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function(supplier_name varchar, supplier_replace varchar)

  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$  
    regex_string = SUPPLIER_REPLACE.replace(/\b:\b/g, '":"').toLowerCase();
    regex_final = '{"' + regex_string.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, '","') + '"}'

    obj = JSON.parse(regex_final);
    
    var supplier = SUPPLIER_NAME.toLowerCase();
    
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (supplier.includes(key)) {
            var new_supplier = obj[key]
        }
    }
    
    return new_supplier;
    
$$;
```

When I call the function in a SQL statement

```
select parent_supplier
    , function(parent_supplier, 'Fedex:Fedex')
from table
```

I get the following error: "JavaScript execution error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') in TEST at ' const supplier = SUPPLIER_NAME.toLowerCase();' position 35 stackstrace: TEST line: 7".

I know this error is because I'm using a column as one of my input variables, but I can't figure out how to  properly call it.

I'd appreciate any help!

Function works testing with a string as the input variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message claims the error is on a line reading this:

```
const supplier = SUPPLIER_NAME.toLowerCase();
```

However, there is no line like that in the UDF code in the question. Instead, the line closest to that line is this one:

```
var supplier = SUPPLIER_NAME.toLowerCase();
```

Since the line with the `const` does not appear in the UDF, this means it must be calling a different version of the UDF. There are a couple of common reasons why this happens. UDFs are owned by a directory and schema, and unless they're explicitly called using a three-part identifier (db_name.schema_name.udf_name), Snowflake will use the current schema in context and use that schema's UDF if there is one with that name and signature. The other reason is that Snowflake supports overloaded UDFs. That means that multiple versions of the same UDF name can exist provided they have different numbers of input parameters or different types of input parameters.

You can check to make sure the SQL is calling the right version of the UDF by placing something like `return "foo"` or some other recognizable return on the first line of the UDF temporarily. If calling it does not return that message (assuming there are no compilation errors) then it's running another version of the UDF.